# How to make ToolTips have rounded corners - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tooltip

I've created a small WPF application and have a number of TextBoxes on the page. All of these TextBoxes have rounded corners.

I have used the MVVM pattern and implemented the IDataErrorInfo interface to display errors to the user. When one of the TextBoxes is empty the edges, ToolTips should be displayed Red which I have successfully done.

I now want the red edge to also have rounded corners like the TextBoxes. As shown in the image the red border is shown as the TextBox is empty, The red border needs to have a corner radius.

[image: Red border shown here]

```
<!-- Text box xaml code that is used to display the error and binding -->
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxBase}"
                             Name="FirstName"
                             Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource CustomerObject}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>


<!-- Code that changes the tool tip if it's null -->
<Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />

            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: I'm rather new to XAML and WPF and rather unsure how to specifically do that

Answer (score 1):

You could create a specific Tooltip Style for errors:

Here an example of a custom Tooltip style with **CornerRadius = "4"**:

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorRoundedTooltip" TargetType="ToolTip">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="4"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
          <ContentPresenter Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Content">
       <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent.ValidationMessage}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ToolTip x:Key="ErrorRepository" Style="{StaticResource ErrorRoundedTooltip}" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource ErrorRepository}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```